# How did a clip from Eurotrip end up in Katy Perry's Last Friday Night?

Tags: music-video, eurotrip

13 minutes into [Eurotrip (2004)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0356150/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), when it cuts to the next day, there is a 4 second clip of a boy riding past a house on his bike and throwing in a newspaper.

[image: Screenshot from Eurotrip]

---

The music video for Katy Perry's [Last Friday Night (2011)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlyXNRrsk4A) starts of with a 20 second clip, of a boy riding down the street and throwing a newspaper at every house. The last house he passees is the exact same as the clip from Eurotrip.

[image: Screenshot from Last Friday Night]

---

How did this end up happening? Did they get permission to use it in the music video? Did some of the same people work on both? Or is it some kind of stock footage used even more places? And is this kind of practice common?

Comment: Likely royalty free stock.

Comment: Reference: http://m.mentalfloss.com/article.php?id=55801

Answer (score 4):

It's quite common for clips from movies and TV shows to be reused for budgetary reasons. It's cheaper than filming new footage that would be more-or-less identical, particularly if some kind of special effect is involved. Some good (and surprising) examples [here](http://screenrant.com/movies-copied-stole-footage-scenes-other-films/).